How to insert blob data into multiple blob column in a table in Oracle stored procedure using php?
I have a table with multiple column whose data type is blob in oracle. Now how can I insert multiple blob data into the table. Following is the example but here there is only one column type of blob but I have multiple blob columns.
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO BTAB (BLOBID, BLOBDATA) '
     .'VALUES(:MYBLOBID, EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING BLOBDATA INTO :BLOBDATA');
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':MYBLOBID', $myblobid);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':BLOBDATA', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);

Can you guide on stored procedure:
PROCEDURE spSaveNewTest(
        pAPPLICATION_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
        pATTACHMENT_FILE_3 IN BLOB,
        pFILE_NAME_3 IN NVARCHAR2,
        pATTACHMENT_FILE_4 IN BLOB,
        pFILE_NAME_4 IN NVARCHAR2,
        P_RESULT OUT NVARCHAR2
)
    AS
    BEGIN
              
        P_RESULT := '99';
        INSERT INTO APPL_ATTCH_STG(APPLICATION_NO,ATTACHMENT_FILE_3,FILE_NAME_3,ATTACHMENT_FILE_4,FILE_NAME_4)     VALUES(pAPPLICATION_NO,EMPTY_BLOB(),pFILE_NAME_3,EMPTY_BLOB(),pFILE_NAME_4) RETURNING ATTACHMENT_FILE_3,ATTACHMENT_FILE_4 INTO pATTACHMENT_FILE_3,pATTACHMENT_FILE_4;
        -- If any exception occurs
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
              log_errors_cpc(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
    END;


If you're successfully inserting data into one column, what prevents you from inserting data into two columns?  Is the code shown not working as expected in some way?  Please clarify the problem you've encountered.

Try something like this:
<?php

// create table t (b1 blob, b2 blob);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$c = oci_connect('cj', 'xxxx', 'localhost/orclpdb1');
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql = <<<'END'
    insert into t (b1, b2)
      values (empty_blob(), empty_blob())
      returning b1, b2 into :myblob1, :myblob2
END;

$stmt = oci_parse($c, $sql);
$lob1 = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
$lob2 = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':myblob1', $lob1, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':myblob2', $lob2, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);

$lob1->write('My first BLOB');
$lob2->write('My second BLOB');

oci_commit($c);

$lob1->free();
$lob2->free();

$s = oci_parse($c, "select * from t");
oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);
$arr = oci_fetch_assoc($s);
$b1 = $arr['B1']->load();
$b2 = $arr['B2']->load();

print $b1 . "\n" . $b2;

?>

The output is:
$ php t.php 
My first BLOB
My second BLOB


Thank you @Christopher Jones, Can you guide on stored procedure.

I Have edited the question as I am getting error in compiling stored procedure.

That's a different topic.  Open a new question for that.

Okay thanks, issue solved.
